# horizontal alignment for section number and section name

Tags: horizontal-alignment

With this code:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[fontsize=8.5pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{helvet}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{varwidth} 
\usepackage{linegoal} 

\titleformat{\section}
  {\fontsize{12pt}{0}\bfseries}{}{0em}
  {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[inner ysep=1.75mm,text width=85mm,
    align=left,left color=black!15,right color=black!15] 
    {\parbox{5mm}{\raggedleft\thesection}\hspace{5mm}\parbox[t][0pt][t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-15mm}{\raggedright #1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2} 
\section{gang}
\section{hound}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

The section name and the section number are somehow displaced (shown with the red line). How can i put the number and the name on the same (red) line?

[image]

Comment: Why are you using parboxes at all?

Comment: You should not use `titlesec` with `scrbook`. Use re-definition of `\sectionlinesformat` to change the formatting of section headings. There is even an example for headings with background color in the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not recommended to use `titlesec` together with a KOMA-Script class. So here is a suggestion without this package:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[fontsize=8.5pt,DIV=calc]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{helvet}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\addtokomafont{section}{\Large}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}
    {\setlength\fboxsep{1.75mm}%
      \colorbox{black!15}{\raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{%
        \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
          \raggedsection\@hangfrom{\hskip#2#3}{#4}%
    }}}}
    {\@hangfrom{\hskip#2#3}{#4}}%
}
\renewcommand\sectionformat{%
  \makebox[10mm][r]{\thesection\autodot\hspace{5mm}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{gang}
\section{hound}
\section{section with a very very long title}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: WOW, this is just great! Thank you so much!

Comment: And how can I get specific fontsize for sections, e.g. 14pt instead of "\large"?

Comment: Then you can use something like`\addtokomafont{section}{\fontsize{14pt}{18pt}\selectfont}`.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply apply `\parbox[t][0pt][t]` to both parboxes with the following result:

[image: correct spacing]

Comment: @GuestUser If it solves your problem, you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

What's the point of usin `TikZ` when a simple `\colorbox` will do the trick?

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[fontsize=8.5pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx} %
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{linegoal}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\fontsize{12pt}{0}\bfseries}{}{0em}
   {\setlength\fboxsep{1.75mm}\colorbox{Gainsboro!40!Lavender}{\makebox[5mm][r]{\thesection}\hspace{5mm}%
   \parbox[t][0pt]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-10mm\relax}{\raggedright#1}}%
  }
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{gang}
\section{hound}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you ask that question, then why should someone would like to use `titlesec` if there are macros like `\setkomafont` and `\sectionformat`?

Comment: @TeXnician: You're perfectly right, but I forgot it was a `scrbook`. Further, I don't know `koma-script` well enough to give an answer with its tools. It also might help people not using koma-script. What I wanted to point is it's needless to use a sledgehammer to crack a nut.